# mysql: select multiple row values in comma separated format using COALESCE

Tags: mysql, sql-server

This is mssql version:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBranchIds]
    @WebsiteId INT,
    @BranchIds VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @BranchIds = COALESCE(@BranchIds + ',', '') + CAST(BranchId AS VARCHAR)
    FROM Dealer WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE WebsiteId = @WebsiteId
END
```

Dealer table has following column:
branchid, websiteid. In output variable of this SP, we get branch ids like:
1265,1265,1265,5,5,5

I am converting this to mysql, I tried:

```
PROCEDURE `GetBranchIds`(
v_WebsiteId int,
out BranchIds varchar(1000))
BEGIN
    set @BranchIds := null;

    select @BranchIds := (CONCAT(COALESCE(CONCAT(BranchIds,','), ''),BranchId))
    from dealer
    where websiteid = v_WebsiteId;
END
```

But I get output in different rows i.e. 1265 in 1st row, 1265 in 2nd row and so on. I want output in comma separated format like 1265,1265,1265,5,5,5. What i am doing wrong in mysql version here?

Comment: I think you should use group_concat() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using group_concat() function:

```
select group_concat(BranchId) INTO @BranchIds
from dealer where websiteid = v_WebsiteId;
```